# Create subfolders, changed namespace but it doesn´t work

Tags: php, namespaces

My data is for example here `test\dashboard\MyWidgets\FolderWhereDataIs`

I moved it to an subfolder, i changed the namespace in this: `test\dashboard\MyWidgets\Subfolder\FolderWhereDataIs` but now it doens´t work..

Comment: "_but now it doens´t work_" is not very descriptive to work with. Do you get a white page? Does your browser crash? Please edit your question and give more detail on what happens and what error/warning you get

Answer (score 0):

do you have cleared cache composer?

it seems to be a cache problem :)

check your **composer.json** and do a `composer dump`

Comment: Why does it seem to be a cache problem? How do you know OP is using composer?

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding blindingly obvious I have made the same mistake. If you changed the namespace to match the folder, did You update both the

```
namespace test\dashboard\MyWidgets\FolderWhereDataIs;
```

and also the use statement in the script file you are using said data

```
use test\dashboard\MyWidgets\FolderWhereDataIs;
```

or

```
use test\dashboard\MyWidgets\FolderWhereDataIs as MyData;
```

I am only asking because Ive forgot this many a times before myself.

edit: also doing a composer dump-autoload after updating any classes or namespaces might fix this.